# Unix search, exclude and parse

Tags: unix

I have a use case which require help.

Following is my folder structure:

```
/home/stage/m1/folder1/att.json
/home/stage/m1/folder1test/att.json
/home/stage/m1/folder2/att.json
/home/stage/m1/folder2test/att.json
/home/stage/m1/folder3/att.json
/home/stage/m1/folder3test/att.json
```

Json file has several attributes. One of them is like:

```
{
 "name" : "customes",
 "value" : "Y"
}
```

I would like to look through all folders/files Except the files inside "*test*" folders and list the name and value of above json property mentioned above.

So the output should be the name and value of "customes" attribute from the folders

```
/home/stage/m1/folder1/att.json
/home/stage/m1/folder2/att.json
/home/stage/m1/folder3/att.json
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Why is this tagged `unix`?  It is very strange to see full pathnames starting with `D:` in a question about unix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grep exclude dir option

```
grep -ril --exclude-dir="*test" "customes" ./
```

Or

```
grep -ril "customes" ./ | grep -v "*test"
```

Comment: Thanks. I also want to print the "value". How can that be done in this?

Comment: you mean value in json?

Comment: Yes the value in json